# Simple email generator with win32com + tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, callback, win32com

Im trying to make a program to generate outlook email with ***tkinter*** and ***win32com***

**What I want:**

- when I select: **SAD** + click on **generate**= display an outlook message *'pfff I'm sad'*
- when I select: **HAPPY** + click on **generate**= display an outlook message *'Thanks I'm happy !'

**Problem:**

- when you run the program and you select either ***SAD*** or **HAPPY** + ***Generate*** it works fine but when you tried the same thing again it gives an **error**: *Exception in Tkinter callback
  Traceback (most recent call last):*   ***see pictures below***

```
    import tkinter as tk
    import win32com.client as client
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    
    outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
    message = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    message.Subject= "My status"
    message.To = "test@tst.com"
    
    #When button is clicked
    def Click ():
        if(var.get()==1):
            message.Body="Thanks im HAPPY !!"
            message.Display()
            
        if(var.get()==2):
            message.Body="Pfff im sad:(("
            message.Display()
            
                       
    #RadioButtons
    var = tk.IntVar()
    
    rdb1 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="HAPPY", variable=var, value=1)
    rdb1.pack()
    rdb2 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="SAD", variable=var, value=2)
    rdb2.pack()
    
    #Button
    BTN=tk.Button(root, text="Generate",command=Click)
    BTN.pack()
    
    
    root.mainloop()
```

If possible I prefer an edit to my code than a different code who do the same thing.

When I click generate for the first time

[image: When I click generate for the first time]

When I close the outlook page and hit Generate for a new message

[image: When I close the outlook page and hit Generate for a new message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
def Click ():
        outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
        message = outlook.CreateItem(0)
        message.Subject= "My status"
        message.To = "test@tst.com"
        if(var.get()==1):
            message.Body="Thanks im HAPPY !!"
            message.Display()
            
        if(var.get()==2):
            message.Body="Pfff im sad:(("
            message.Display()
```

Comment: Why did you put `outlook = client.Dispatch(...)` inside the function? Given the other answer, it doesn't look like that is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to move the creation of the message into the click function. This way you do not continue to interact with the same `message` which seems to be your issue.

```py
outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

#When button is clicked
def Click ():

    message = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    message.Subject= "My status"
    message.To = "test@tst.com"

    if(var.get()==1):
        message.Body="Thanks im HAPPY !!"
        message.Display()
            
    if(var.get()==2):
        message.Body="Pfff im sad:(("
        message.Display()
```

Comment: Just a quick question: Why didn't you also move `outlook = client.Dispatch(...)` inside the function?

Comment: Because the outlook application only needs to be instantiated once. It’s like saying every time you click the button you want a bucket to be filled with black or white water. The water would be the message. Each time you click the button you don’t want a new bucket (outlook), instead you want new water (message).

Comment: Thx for the explanation. I haven't used `win32com` before. I've used `win32api` and other parts of `pywin32` before but never `win32com`

Comment: It did thanks. Let's see if this helps OP though.